# How to create "dynamic group" in ldap?

Tags: ldap, openldap, ou, apache-directory, object-class

I want to create **dynamic group** in openldap with  *Apache Directory Studio* but `groupOfURLs`  object class not available.

[image: Apache Directory Studio add object class window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic group feature is not present by default (that's why you can't find the `groupOfURLs` object class). You need to define and add the `dyngroup.schema` to cn=config.

The dyngroup definition can be found here : [dyngroup.ldif](https://github.com/openldap/openldap/blob/master/servers/slapd/schema/dyngroup.ldif)

Then, for the dynamic group feature to work, you need to enable the dynlist overlay, which also need to be defined, see [slapo-dynlist](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-dynlist&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release).

You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap/issues/355) as a kind of walk through.

Comment: Nb. If you don't know how to add schema configs and/or overlays, this is another issue which is already addressed on SO.